# Simple mysql query displaying results in specific order

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created 2 table messages and Conversation.

Conversation table will create an unique id for two users who is sending and receiving messages.

Messages table will contains all info of user messages.

**Conversation table**

```
conversation_id | user_id1 | user_id2 |last_message_id
      1              5          1           4
      2              5          2           5

message_id  | conversation_id | sender_id |  message |  created_time
   1           1                   5          MSG A     2012-06-10 00:20:04
   2           1                   5          MSG B     2012-06-10 00:20:21
   3           1                   5          MSG C     2012-06-10 00:21:09
   4           1                   1          MSG D     2012-06-10 00:22:23
   5           2                   5          MSG E     2012-06-10 00:25:16
```

**Output I want:**

```
sender_id | message | created_time
   5        MSG E     2012-06-10 00:25:16
   1        MSG D     2012-06-10 00:22:23
```

**What I tried:**

```
SELECT * FROM conversation c, messages m 
WHERE c.user_id1='$userid' OR c.user_id2='$userid'
AND c.last_message_id=m.message_id
ORDER BY created_time DESC
```

But this query is not displaying right result.

Do we need something like following to group by as well?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE CONDITION
(SELECT MAX(created_time)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY SOMEFEILD)
order by time desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your query like this

```
SELECT * FROM conversation c, messages m 
WHERE (c.user_id1='$userid' OR c.user_id2='$userid')
AND c.last_message_id=m.message_id
ORDER BY created_time DESC
```